# I am facing a problem while running reactjs application.Given below is the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Html Webpack Plugin:

```
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ../../../../oop2(C#)/After_Semester/miniReactProject/practice/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modu  les/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\nod  e_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoad  er.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\  lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRu  nner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Nor  malModule.js:812:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Normal  Module.js:956:15)
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1367:12
  ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../../../oop2(C#)/After_Semester/miniReactProject/practice/node_modules/react  -scripts/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\nod  e_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoad  er.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\  lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRu  nner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Nor  malModule.js:812:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Normal  Module.js:956:15)
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1367:12
      at processResult (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModul  e.js:751:19)
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:853:5
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:  11
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:185:  11
      at loadLoader (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoad  er.js:33:11)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\  lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRu  nner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Nor  malModule.js:812:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Normal  Module.js:956:15)
      at E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1367:12
  
  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
  
  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27
  
  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  
  
  
  
  
  - Compilation.js:1367 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
  
  - ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../../../oop2(C#)/After_Semester/miniReactProject/practice/node_modules/rea    ct-scripts/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  
  - Error: Cannot find module 'E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\n    ode_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  
  - Require stack:
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  
  - - E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject\practice\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  
  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
  
  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27
  
  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  
  
  
  
  
  - Compilation.js:1367 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
  
  
  - NormalModule.js:853 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:853:5
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:399 
    [practice]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:185 
    [practice]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:185:11
  
  
  
  
  
  
  - Compilation.js:1367 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
  
  - child-compiler.js:169 
    [practice]/[react-scripts]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
  
  - Compiler.js:559 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:559:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1129 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1129:17
  
  
  
  - Compiler.js:1125 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1125:33
  
  
  - Compilation.js:3087 
    [practice]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:3087:11
```

Comment: This line should give you a good start what to check: `Error: Cannot find module 'E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\miniReactProject...`

Answer (score 0):

remove node_module folder and install all the packages again by running

```
npm install
```